# Run function in background while leaving UI interactable C# Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, xamarin.android

i want to run this function(s) in background

```
        private void SetPosters()
        {
            foreach(var i in posters)
            { 
                i.SetImageBitmap(GetImageBitmapFromUrl(getLinkfromTag((i.Tag).ToString())));
            }
        }
```

```
        private static string getLinkfromTag(String tag)
        {
            String Link = "-";
            foreach(var i in movies_Arr)
            {
                if(i.Id == tag)
                {
                    Link = i.HorizontalPoster;
                }
            }
            return Link;
        }
```

```
        private static Bitmap GetImageBitmapFromUrl(string url)
        {
            Bitmap imageBitmap = null;

            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                var imageBytes = webClient.DownloadData(url);
                if (imageBytes != null && imageBytes.Length > 0)
                {
                    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
                }
            }

            return imageBitmap;
        }
```

i cant interact with my UI when the images are being downloaded from the web

Other Info -

posters is a listview containing all the imageviews from the activity
movies_Arr is a listview containing links for the posters

Comment: Have a look for async/await

Comment: The funny part is then you forgot to past the SetImageBitmap code, because you have to run everything async except code inside this method that has to be run on ui thread to access ui elements

Answer (score 0):

You can run your method using a fire and forget approach by executing `CommandSetPosters` command or just calling `LaunchPosters()`. The execution will NOT be awaited, totally async. Notice that we call `SetImageBitmap` on ui tread, otherwise you couldn't access UI elements properly.

```
 public ICommand CommandSetPosters
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command<object>((object context) =>
            {
                LaunchPosters(context);
            });
        }
    }

    public void LaunchPosters(object param)
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            //can use param from command if needed
            SetPosters();

        }).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

private void SetPosters()
{
    foreach (var i in posters)
    {
        var bitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(getLinkfromTag((i.Tag).ToString()));


        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
        {
            // Update the UI
            i.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: umm i am sorry i am really new to this what is ICommand and when i checked online it give `{Binding Path=UpdateCommand}` this but i created imageviews dynamically so i cant do that

Comment: As said above if you don't wonna use command just run LaunchPosters(null);